# How do I control where game pieces go for checkerboard in Python?

Tags: python

So, I have asked a similar question before, but I was still unable to solve my problem. I need to make a checkerboard with 6 game pieces evenly on each side. This code was helpful, but it randomly distributes the game pieces, I've played around with it in multiple lines and attempted to understand but it's not clicking for me. How can I get six pieces to be on top half and six to be on lower half with space in the middle? Like a regular checkerboard set up?

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randrange

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
SQUARE_SIZE = 40
SQUARES_PER_SIDE = 8

def drawRect(color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for iterations in range(4):
        turtle.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()

def pushTurtleForward():
    turtle.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)

def drawHorizontal(inverted=False):
    if inverted:
        for horizontal in range(SQUARES_PER_SIDE):
            if horizontal > 0:
                if horizontal % 2 == 1:
                    pushTurtleForward()
                    drawRect("white")
                else:
                    pushTurtleForward()
                    drawRect("black")
            else:
                drawRect("black")
    else:
        for horizontal in range(SQUARES_PER_SIDE):
            if horizontal > 0:
                if horizontal % 2 == 1:
                    pushTurtleForward()
                    drawRect("black")
                else:
                    pushTurtleForward()
                    drawRect("white")
            else:
                drawRect("white")

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("Grey")

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')

for drawVertical in range(SQUARES_PER_SIDE):
    turtle.setposition(0, SQUARE_SIZE * drawVertical)

    if drawVertical % 2 == 0:
        drawHorizontal(inverted=True)
    else:
        drawHorizontal()

# Checker graphics demonstration.  Distribute 12 red checkers around
# black squares on board without any two landing on the same spot.

red_checkers = []

for _ in range(12):
    checker = Turtle('circle')
    checker.color('black', 'red')
    checker.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
    checker.penup()

    red_checkers.append(checker)

    position = checker.position()  # a position guaranteed to fail

    while any(map(lambda checker, p=position: checker.distance(p) < 
SQUARE_SIZE/2, red_checkers)):
        x, y = 0, 1  # a parity guaranteed to fail

        while x % 2 != y % 2:
            x, y = (SQUARES_PER_SIDE),(SQUARES_PER_SIDE)

        position = (x * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE/2, y * SQUARE_SIZE + 
SQUARE_SIZE/2)

    checker.goto(position)


screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you insert a piece to a specific spot on the board?  And can you remove a piece from a specific spot on the board?

Comment: @touchmyboomboom Hmm, do you mean make a loop for each different game piece?

Comment: I mean, if you number the squares of the gameboard 1 - 64 (or 0 - 63), you can assign red to squares 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 (or something like that).  It also makes moving easier: if red wants to move from 17 to 24, you just remove the piece at 17 and add one to 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Replace the `for _ in range(12):` loop with this:

```
# Returns the drawing co-ords of checker space
def get_square_coords(row, col):
    return (col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE/2, row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE/2)

# Creates 2 rows of checkers
def create_checkers(row, color):
    checkers = []
    col = 0
    for y in range(row, row+2):
        for x in range(col, SQUARES_PER_SIDE, 2):
            checker = Turtle('circle')
            checker.color('black', color)
            checker.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
            checker.penup()
            position = get_square_coords(y, x)
            checker.goto(position)
            checkers.append(checker)
        col += 1
    return checkers

red_checkers = create_checkers(0, 'red')
green_checkers = create_checkers(6, 'green')
```

It creates this:
[image]

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for, thank you very much. I just need to get it on both sides. I appreciate it

Comment: @AySeven I've updated it to draw red and green checkers.

Comment: Ahhh I see! Thank you so much! This makes so much more sense then what I was originally trying to do.